# TypeError: Cannot read property 'txdate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have create my json file: BuyDT in that i put a property "txdate":"2019-07-17". and in SellDT i also do that. But when i call statement:

```
 while (SellDT[0].txdate<BuyDT[0].txdate) {
            SellDT.shift()
        }
```

it notify that: can not read property "txt" undefine. I'm search on google but not get answer

google, stackoverflow,....etc..

```
BuyDT:
[
    {
        "symbol": "CTF",
        "orderqtty": 10,
        "orderamt": 5000,
        "txdate": "2019-07-15"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "CTF",
        "orderqtty": 5,
        "orderamt": 7000,
        "txdate": "2019-07-16"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "CTF",
        "orderqtty": 15,
        "orderamt": 5000,
        "txdate": "2019-07-17"
    }
]
and SellDT is same:
[

    {
        "symbol": "COM",
        "orderqtty": 16,
        "orderamt": 8000,
        "txdate": "2019-07-17"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "COM",
        "orderqtty": 16,
        "orderamt": 8000,
        "txdate": "2019-07-17"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce. Can you post a [mcve]? What is probably going on is that your condition is always true and you shift off all of `SellDT` until it's empty, at which point you try to access a property on undefined.

Comment: Please share code where you called SellDT[0].txdate